# Save data and Open PDF in another browser tab

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to save my data to the database first, then open a jasper report PDF.Below is my Servlet code.

```
public class insertMedicationSrvlt extends HttpServlet
{

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        MedicationsTbl medTbl=new MedicationsTbl();
        int idPatient = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idPatient"));

        boolean actInact=Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("activeInactive"));

        String insertResult="NA";

        String ptInstructionsTxt=request.getParameter("ptInstructionsTxt").trim();

        int quantityTxt=0;

        if(!request.getParameter("quantityTxt").isEmpty())
        {
          quantityTxt=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantityTxt"));
        }

        String drug=request.getParameter("drugTxt").trim();
        String dispenseFromTxt=request.getParameter("dispenseFromTxt").trim();
        String refilTxt=request.getParameter("refilTxt").trim();
        String exerciseTxt=request.getParameter("exerciseTxt").trim();
        String therapyTxt=request.getParameter("therapyTxt").trim();

        String save = request.getParameter("save");
        System.out.println(save);


        Date startedDateTxt=null;

        if(!request.getParameter("startedDateTxt").isEmpty()) 
        {
         startedDateTxt=Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("startedDateTxt"));
        }

        try
        {
           if(!( quantityTxt==0&& ptInstructionsTxt.isEmpty() &&drug.isEmpty() && refilTxt.isEmpty()&& exerciseTxt.isEmpty()&&therapyTxt.isEmpty() &&startedDateTxt==null))
           {               
              insertResult=medTbl.insertMedication(idPatient, actInact, ptInstructionsTxt, quantityTxt, drug, dispenseFromTxt, refilTxt, exerciseTxt, therapyTxt, startedDateTxt);           
              request.getSession().setAttribute("resultMessage", insertResult);


              try
            {
                if(save.equals("print"))
              {
                int idUser=Integer.parseInt(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("UserID").toString());
                int idSubUser=Integer.parseInt(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("SubUserID").toString());


                //Get company info
                UserTable userTable = new UserTable();
                UserBean userBean = userTable.findUserDetails(idUser);

                //Get Doctor info
                SubUserTable subUserTable = new SubUserTable();
                SubUserBean subUserBean = subUserTable.findSubUser(idSubUser);

                //Get Patient info
                Demographics demographics = new Demographics();
                List<DemographicsBean> demographicsBean = demographics.findDemo(idPatient);


                //Print the report
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("companyName",userBean.getCompanyName().trim());
                params.put("companyPhone",userBean.getPhone().trim());



                request.getSession().setAttribute("data", params);


                Connection connection = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();

                JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ReportResources/Prescription2.jasper"), params,connection);
                byte[] exportReportToPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

                ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType("application/pdf;");

                JRPdfExporter jRPdfExporter = new  JRPdfExporter();
                jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");

                jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, sout);
                jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");

                request.setAttribute("exportIndentObject", jRPdfExporter);

                //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "myReport.pdf");
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");
                sout.write(exportReportToPdf);
                sout.flush();
                sout.close();
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("resultMessage", Common.SAVE_ROLLBACK);
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally
        {
           response.sendRedirect("medicationsDisplayAllSrvlt?idPatient="+idPatient+"&activeStatus=true");


        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Below is the form which calls the above servlet.

```
 <form id="addForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="insertMedicationSrvlt?idPatient=${param.idPatient}">
<!--form elements-->
<button type="submit" name = "save" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">Save</button>
        <button id="printBtn" type="submit" name = "save" class="btn btn-primary" value="print" >Save and Print</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Now when I press the "Save and Print" button, the data is getting saved and "in the same window",the PDF opens.

I tried below to get rid of this.

1. Using `target="_blank"` in form tag: This opened a windows for the PDF, but the form "modal" was still open in the other tab and untill I manually refresh that page, the new data didnt appear. This happened because the `sendredirect` wasn't called I guess.
2. calling "Print" servlet from `insertMedicationSrvlt` servlet: This didn't work too, PDF opened in the same window.

Now what I really need to do is;

1. User press the "Save and Print" button.
2. Form get submitted to the `insertMedicationSrvlt` and data get saved.
3. `insertMedicationSrvlt` call the servlet which refresh the JSP page.
4. Now I am in the JSP page. Now the new "PDF" opens in another tab.

How can I do this?

Comment: you want the data submitted by the user to remain visible (the form inputs holds their data after submitting )?, and then the generated pdf page opens in another tab right ? P.S override the service method instead of calling the processRequest from the doPost and doGet

Comment: @QuakeCore:  Form input don't hold the data after submitting. after submitting, the servlet redirects it to a "loader" servlet where all the new data will be loaded. These data will be displayed in JSP.

Comment: Well I am also doing the same thing in my project . Mine is ASP.NET platform. I am sending content through Ajax to the controller which in turn calls DAL to save the content in the db . I made `async : false` in my Ajax and wrote `window.open("your url")` at the last line of success . So after the whole data when gets saved in the db , and due to  `async : false` , the new tab is only opened after the entire things gets saved into the db .By this I always get the updated content in my PDF Rendering.